# Parrot OS Wifi Problems

Tags: wifi, drivers, firmware, iwlwifi, parrotsec

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad E15 Gen4, with the *Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)* PCI wifi card.

I have a fresh dual-boot install of Parrot OS and I'm having a very hard time getting Wifi to work.

Here is the full *lspci -v* output of the card:

```
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 9
    Memory at 601d1cc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

I have tried using iwlwifi without success, this is my first time installing firmware or dealing with issues like this, so I'm willing to try again with a comprehensive walkthrough.

I have run the google gauntlet, but after a few hours I haven't found any results yet. I tried most/all of the youtube guides instructing to download github repos, I assume half of those are for generic realtek or USB devices.

Any tips or information I can provide, please let me know!

Comment: It looks like the firmware is there. Does it work with a less niche Linux distro that's not optimized for network testing? E.g., if you just download the Ubuntu 22.10 Live USB image, and boot your laptop from a USB pen drive prepared with that, does wifi work?

Answer (score 0):

Took me about 2 hours but somehow this guide didn't present itself on google until now: https://www.howtogeek.com/806845/linux-not-detecting-wi-fi-adapter/

With `sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` where *iwlwifi* is the type of driver my Wifi card uses, I was able to see that there was a single firmware file that wasn't present to load. I did a `locate` on it, found it was in a subdirectory of /lib/firmware and moved into the top level file. Reboot and it worked!